# How to use skrollr library (div text not show)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in html and css and javascript  I want to build my first onepage website and I'm using [skrollr library](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) but I don't know why I can not use it in true way I have 2 div in my index file and styles in css file, when I write something on second div it does not show and its hide behind  the first div [here is my code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6rnB/)

```
  <div id="please-scroll"  data-0="opacity: 1;" data-800="opacity: 0;">  
      please scroll to see Dinosaurs life story
  </div>
  <div id="next_generation" data-800="opacity:1;" data-1000="opacity: 0;">
      please scroll moreeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
  </div>
```

and here is my css

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 4500px;
    width:100%;
}



#please-scroll{
position:absolute;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:red;
text-align: center;
z-index:100;
}
#next_generation{

height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:yellow;
text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Paste your code here and make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

for tag div should be:

```
div class="..."
```

not

```
div id="..."
```

Comment: it does not make any changes to my code result and my problem

Comment: approximately I think the problem is in position of divs but i dont know how can i solve it and i don't like to use exact pixel for example 200px for first div and 400px for second in my css file like this height:200px